# iPhone : access constant values

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, constants

I've defined some constants like

```
#define val_a @"A"
#define val_b @"B"
#define val_c @"C"
```

Now I've some keys which having the same name as constants I've defined, I want to print value of constants (without using **constant key**). I've tried,

```
- (NSString *) actualValForKey:(NSString *)key 
 {
     return key; //It will return **key** parameter, but I want to return the **constant value** as defined
 }
```

I can write like `NSLog(@"Value = %@", [self actualValForKey:keys]);` as all keys are dynamic, and I can't write `NSLog(@"Value = %@", val_a);` in this way.

Here, `keys` will be come as `NSString`.

P.S. Constant identification.

Is it possible? alternatives?

Comment: keys=val_a; NSLog(@"Value = %@", [self actualValForKey:keys]);

Comment: I've edited question more clearly. I don't know which keys would be use, all will come dynamically.

Comment: ` I've some keys which having the same name as constants I've defined` means you can have val_a as a key? or @"A" as a key?

Comment: of course `val_a` as **key** and **A** is *value*.

Comment: Please check my answer and comment is your work done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for looking out for this, finally I've solution it as beginner way! ;)

```
- (NSString *) actualValForKey:(NSString *)key 
 {
     NSString *str = @"";

     if([key isEqualToString:val_a])
     {
        str = @"A";
     }
     else if([key isEqualToString:val_b])
     {
        str = @"B";
     }
     .
     .
     return str;
 }
```

P.S. Need to update `#define` with same name as **constant**.

Answer (score 1):

In C++/ObjectiveC you can not get the name of the macro in runtime. Because, **The macro name is replaced by a copy of the macro body**.

You can read documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/503x3e3s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> The #define directive is typically used to associate meaningful
>   identifiers with constants, keywords, and commonly used statements or
>   expressions. Identifiers that represent constants are sometimes called
>   "symbolic constants" or "manifest constants." Identifiers that
>   represent statements or expressions are called "macros." In this
>   preprocessor documentation, only the term "macro" is used. When the
>   name of the macro is recognized in the program source text or in the
>   arguments of certain other preprocessor commands, it is treated as a
>   call to that macro. The macro name is replaced by a copy of the macro
>   body. If the macro accepts arguments, the actual arguments following
>   the macro name are substituted for formal parameters in the macro
>   body. The process of replacing a macro call with the processed copy of
>   the body is called "expansion" of the macro call.

But, if you really need. You can write build script, which parse all the `#define` directives in your file and creates a NSDictionary. Which you can use in your code.

For example, I added a file. Which shows the correct use of scripts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is pre-processor, as soon as you write `keys=val_a` `val_a gets` replaced by @"A", and that @"A" is sent to the method.

As per naming conventions, all macros should be in block letters so that you may not end up with same name in variables.

```
#define VAL_A @"A"
#define VAL_B @"B"
#define VAL_C @"C"
```

Or if you need to do something similar you can create a dictionary with all set of keyValues.

EDIT:

If you use this define then it will convert your passed value to string and you can store it in key.

```
#define RET_NAME(n) #n

NSString *key=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", RET_NAME(val_a)];
```

Now the `key` will store `val_a`.

Answer (score 0):

I unusually separate the names and the values the following way, use #defines or const strings to define the names of things and then stuff the actual value into a dictionary. The reason is that this will survive migration to external sources for your values better than a plain #define. Also it plays well with other methods like NSUserDefaults e.g (this is off the cuff)

```
#define kNameForThing
#define kNameForOtherThing

- (void) initValues {
   // _defaults is a NSDictionary
   _defaults = @{
        kNameForThing : @"A",
        KNameForOtherThing : @"B"
   };
}

- (void) useValue {
   NSString value = _defaults[kNameForThing];
   ....
}
```

You can do all sorts of consistency tests on, check wether the value exists wether all the expected keys are there and so on, this becomes more important if you load this information from a file

Also using more expressive names for things will help you in the long run. 
This is using the new objective c literal syntax for easier object creation and access